# Why do positives and negatives not usually co-exist?

Tags: negation

If I drink half of a bottle of water, there's half of a bottle of water and there's not half of a bottle of water. However, why is the negative sentence not usually used? Is it a wrong sentence?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking about parts of speech, people's behavior, or what?

Comment: @FeliniusRex help me...

Comment: _There's not half of a bottle_ is not an idiomatic phrase. We say the bottle is _half full_ or _half-empty_. https://hrmexplorer.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/is-your-glass-half-full-or-half-empty/

Comment: Ok, you completely changed it. Thanks -- that helps some. I agree with @KateBunting - Nobody says "There's not half a bottle..." The reason is because that gets the concept wrong. The bottle is always there. The amount of fluid is what changes. Another way to think about it -- why is that important? If you have a bottle of something, how much is left, and the bottle are the things you have -- not some abstract not half a bottle.